# how to identify in a query whether the table has a Primary key or not

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

Is it possible to write a query that determines if the table has a primary key or not?

```
SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID('TRS') and xtype = PK
```

If it doesn't have primary then it will return nothing.

In this [link](http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?31307-sysindexes-how-to-distinguish-primary-key-index&p=76395#post76395) the author said about using `Xtype` but it seems it's an old term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you the key and it's column name if there is a primary key, else nothing.

```
SELECT sysobjects.name, syscolumns.name
FROM
  sysobjects INNER JOIN 
  syscolumns ON syscolumns.id = sysobjects.id INNER JOIN
  syskeys ON syskeys.id = sysobjects.id
WHERE 
  sysobjects.type = 'U' AND syskeys.type = 1
```